# Probability that a 5 card hand contains all 4 cards of a rank given that I know that the hand contains at least 3 cards of a rank.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

The correct approach here seems to be to calculate all the possibilities that a hand contains 4 cards of the same rank (A) and all the possibilities that it contains exactly 3 cards of the same rank (B). Then the probability is equal to $\frac {A}{A+B}$. Where in this case: $A = 13 * 48$, $B = 13 *{48 \choose 2} * {4 \choose 3}$.

I understand this approach, but I am struggling to understand why it is (assumingly) wrong to transform the problem to the following: Three cards (all the same rank) have been removed from the deck, so the deck contains 49 cards and 2 will be dealt. There is only 1 card left in the deck that I need to get in order to have 4 of the same rank (including the 3 three that were removed in the beginning). What would be the correct probability in this situation, and why is it different (if at all) to the original problem?

Comment: For any probability problem stated with a "... given that..." I would immediately think of conditional probability and Bayes Theorem. Look at that and see if you can't think of something.

Comment: In your suggestion, the new problem is : what is the probability to have 4 aces, knowing that we already have Ace Clubs, Diamond and Hearts.  In the original problem, we don't specify which aces are already known as present in the hand.

Comment: I would assume that in the problem as formulated $A=\binom{48}1$ and $B=\binom{48}2$.